# Explanation of `ch[:prefix_len%len(ch)]` in python program

Tags: python

I am looking [at this python program](http://code.activestate.com/recipes/306863-printing-a-bannertitle-line/) and almost understood its flow but I am unable to understand `ch[:prefix_len%len(ch)]` in the following part:

```
else:
            prefix = ch * (prefix_len/len(ch)) + ch[:prefix_len%len(ch)]
            suffix = ch * (suffix_len/len(ch)) + ch[:suffix_len%len(ch)]
```

Here is the context:

```
def banner(text, ch='=', length=78):
    if text is None:
        return ch * length
    elif len(text) + 2 + len(ch)*2 > length:
        # Not enough space for even one line char (plus space) around text.
        return text
    else:
        remain = length - (len(text) + 2)
        prefix_len = remain / 2
        suffix_len = remain - prefix_len
        if len(ch) == 1:
            prefix = ch * prefix_len
            suffix = ch * suffix_len
        else:
            prefix = ch * (prefix_len/len(ch)) + ch[:prefix_len%len(ch)]
            suffix = ch * (suffix_len/len(ch)) + ch[:suffix_len%len(ch)]
        return prefix + ' ' + text + ' ' + suffix
```

Could somebody please help me to understand this. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sure!
`ch[:prefix_len % len(ch)]` is accessing a **slice** of the ch sequence starting from the beginning (since there's no value before the `:` and going to one character before the index defined by `prefix_len % len(ch)`.

This value is `prefix_len` (defined earlier as the length of the prefix, not surprisingly) modulus the length of `ch`. (Think of it as the remainder left over after integer division of `prefix_len / len(ch)`.

I ran the function like: `print(banner("Hello everyone!", "1234"))` and got:
`123412341234123412341234123412 Hello everyone! 1234123412341234123412341234123`
so you can see it's fitting the `ch` value (`1234` in my case) in the space it has.

Comment: I am still not getting it. I am confused. Please explain more

Comment: What part don't you understand (so I know where to focus the answer)?
Slicing works like `sequence[start:end]` so if you had:
`data = 'abcdefg'` then `data[:3]`  #results in `'abc'`
or is it modulus (%) that you're not sure about? `7 % 3` yields `1` as there is 1 left over after evenly dividing 7 by 3.

Comment: Thanks,  now I understood.

Answer (score 1):

They're adding the remainder.

Say **prefix = 10**, and **ch = '#&+'**

If you just multiply **ch** by **prefix_len / len(ch)**, you'll get **9**, but you know you need 10.

So **ch[:prefix_len % len(ch)]** is just indexing into **ch** string for the remainder.

Make sense?

Comment: I am still not getting it. I am confused. Please explain more